# RESTful API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I am very new to rails and following a tutorial for RESTful API so let me excuse if it is of not very good quality as I am equally a starter for these kind of terminologies as well.

I created a controller kitten with a command `rails g controller kitten index`

and in the index method I posted this code -

```
class KittenController < ApplicationController
  def index
    require 'open-uri'

    kittens = open('http://placekitten.com/')
    response_status = kittens.status
    response_body = kittens.read[559, 441]

    puts response_status
    puts response_body
  end
end
```

and un commented `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'` in `routes.rb`

When i navigate through this - `http://localhost:3000/kitten`

this is what i am getting in my browser -

> Kitten#index
>
> Find me in app/views/kitten/index.html.erb

and this in my command line -->

[image: billi]

Now my question why it so although i am expecting it in my browser but the cat is shown in command prompt instead of browser ..i am new to rest resource so please excuse if it is a bad one :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what tutorial you're following, but doing this seems like a very odd thing to do for Rails in general and learning RESTful APIs in particular.

Anyway, the `puts` in your controller outputs text to Ruby's standard out, which is going to be the terminal where the server started. That's why this is appearing in the console rather than in your browser: `puts` is putting it there.

If you want this to appear in a web page, you'll need to make a view for that controller action. Perhaps following further along your tutorial will get you there: if not, you might want to find a better one.

Comment: I am following this lesson http://www.codecademy.com/courses/ruby-beginner-en-pEdhY/0?curriculum_id=5122d5f811fbdb5456005922#!/exercises/0

Comment: let me know what i am doing wrong as i am learning rails on my own so plz advise is it a wrong way to learn rails ? as you just mentioned -> "I don't know what tutorial you're following, but doing this seems like a very odd thing to do for Rails in general and learning RESTful APIs in particular."

Comment: Oh! Okay, well this lesson doesn't happen in Rails at all, really. I think you're supposed to be doing this in the little code window on the right-hand side of the article. No Rails or controller stuff involved. Continue following along this tutorial; it actually looks pretty high quality.

Comment: I already completed all Ruby language lessons at codecademy/codeschool/tryruby so thought to implement it in rails ..let me know your thoughts bro :)

Comment: I had never heard of [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) before Google, but it looks cute. Maybe give that a shot?

Comment: thx a lot bro ..I completed free tuts for this site as well...but i am looking for some real action now :) [although few basic parts still left to cover, like this one]

Answer (score 3):

You should read the [Model-View-Controller rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture).

> Controllers provide the “glue” between models and views. In Rails, controllers are responsible for processing the incoming requests from the web browser, interrogating the models for data, and passing that data on to the views for presentation.

Define your variable in the controller and display it in the view:

```
class KittenController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @variable = 'Hello World'
  end
end
```

In your view (app/views/kitten/index.html.erb):

```
<%= @variable %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails controllers setup responses with a [render call](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).
When the call is not performed it instantiates the appropriate view and renders that view. In your case that is index.html.erb

Try this:

```
render :text => kittens.read[559, 441], :status => kittens.status
```